# Laravel Route Filters in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Does `Laravel 5` has route filters like `Laravel 4`, or was it removed in version 5? Where is the directory in Laravel 5, in version 4 it is in app/filters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filters in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373850/filters-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters are now in [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware).

Answer (score 1):

Use middleware instead of filter, in laravel 5